Prove that if it's known where the basis vectors of a vector space map to , the linearly transformation is uniquely determined.

Proving that if it's known where the basis vectors of a vector space
map to , the linearly transformation is uniquely determined.

In other words, say a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ exists , such that the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$ are $\{e_1,e_2 , \dots, e_m\}$, and $m\geq n$.
now let $$v \in \mathbb{R^m}, v= \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_ke_k$$
so $$T(v)=. T(\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_ke_k)= \sum_{k=1}^ma_kT(e_k)$$
Now as it's known where the basis vector end up, one can determine where any other point in $\mathbb{R}^m$  ends up. As the mapping of the basis vectors is unique, it follows that the mapping of any linear combination of their basis vectors is unique too.
I feel this doesn't prove uniqueness well enough, how do I improve it

There is no explicit question in your post + https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

This does "prove uniqueness well enough".

If two linear maps $T,S:V\to W$ map a basis onto the same elements, i.e. $T(v)=S(v)$ for all basis elements, then $P(x):=T(x)-S(x)$ is also a linear map from $V$ to $W$ that maps all elements out of the basis to $0_W$. Since it then maps everything to zero we get $$P(x)=0=T(x)-S(x)\Leftrightarrow T(x)=S(x)$$ for all $x\in V$
